# How can I plot against a curved path on an svg at specific x positions on the path?

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, raphael

I have a 2 rows of circles (imagine 2 rows of seats in a seating chart) that are on straight line, like this:

[image: Seating Chart with straight circles]

I need to curve the rows relative to the longest row (ie row B). I can correctly calculate the curve of each row:

[image]

Row B's circles follow the path correctly, but I need row A's circles to also follow the path as well. You can see that the circles are off. I need the X position of each circle to stay fixed, but Y to  follow that direction of the path.  I'm trying to calculate what the Y position of each circle in row A would be based on it's Y's position on that path, but can't seem to figure it out. Is there a specific calculation on this?

The way I'm attempting this is:

```
      row.seats.forEach((seat, index) => {
          const offset = index * spacing;
          const point =  curvePath.getPointAtLength(offset); 
      ;
         var curveY = point.y; //keep x fixed and only move y
         seat.attr('cy', curveY);
     })
```

Not getting the expected result. I  need to find the Y position of that path if I were to center row A's circles on to that path so it ultimately looks like this:

[image: Correct Curved Path]

How can I determine the path Y position of each circle based on the circle's x position? I've posted a codepen here to demo the paths: https://codepen.io/iamakimmer/pen/eYKOawd. I'm using RaphaelJS but ultimately it's SVG paths and shapes.

Comment: Have tou used pathLength?

Comment: Your curved path starts quite way to the left of the start of straight path A. Find the startOffset value that has the same x as the start of A, and add that to your offset: `const offset = index * spacing + startOffset`. How you compute that startOffset depends on the nature of your curved path.